# How to create an array like this in powershell?

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-4.0, excel-automation

I need to store data like below for TextToColumns Excel automation.
I need to implement Code-2 or Code-3 or Code-4 is that any way to achieve?
I have more than 350+ data so I cant use Code-1, that's not fair for me.

**Code-1: working fine**

```
$var = (1,2),(2,2),(3,2),(4,2),(5,2),(6,2)........(300,2)
$ColumnA.texttocolumns($colrange,1,-412,$false,$false,$false,$false,$false,$true,"|",$var)
```

**Code-2: not Working**

```
$var = @((1,2)..(300,2))
$ColumnA.texttocolumns($colrange,1,-412,$false,$false,$false,$false,$false,$true,"|",$var)
```

**Code-3: not Working**

```
$var = @()
   
#forloop upto 300 
{ $var += ($i,2) }

$ColumnA.texttocolumns($colrange,1,-412,$false,$false,$false,$false,$false,$true,"|",$var)
```

**Code-4: not Working**

```
[array]$var = 1..300 | foreach-object { ,@($_, 2) }
$ColumnA.texttocolumns($colrange,1,-412,$false,$false,$false,$false,$false,$true,"|",$var)
```

Comment: `$var = @(1..300) | ForEach-Object { ,$(@($_,2)) }`?

Comment: Bro code-2, code-3, your code also working fine to assign values
but thats not working with Text-To-Columns function.... giving error

Comment: if I run e.g. `$var1 = (1,2),(2,2),(3,2); $var2 = @(1..3) | ForEach-Object { ,$(@($_,2))` then `Compare-Object $var1 $var2 -IncludeEqual` shows that objects `$var1` and `$var2` are identical…

Comment: check this code bro, i have placed two files in below link
you can take and run it on your system
https://github.com/dinesh-ponnusamy/powershell-code
comment line-32 and uncomment line-29 vice-versa to see the error

Comment: Sorry, I can't use `Excel.Application` COM object not having valid  _Excel_  license…

Comment: Where does this data come from? Sounds like a CSV file that uses the pipe symbol `|` as delimiter. In that case, simply convert that to the delimiter char your Excel understands. Something like `Import-Csv -Path 'theOriginal.csv -Delimiter '|' | Export-Csv -Path 'theNew.csv -UseCulture -NoTypeInformation'`. Next, simply double-click this new file to open in Excel. NoTextToColumns needed then.

Comment: Requirement is pipe delimited txt file to excel conversion. so i opened pipe delimited txt file in excel, then TextToColumn and adding some headers and some excel functionalities and saving as an xlsx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't fully explain what happens here but I guess that it is related to the fact that the [`texttocolumns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns) requires an (deferred) ***expression*** rather than an (evaluated) ***object***.

Meaning that the following appears to work for the [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from [@mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton):

```
$Var = Invoke-Expression ((1..6 |% { "($_, `$xlTextFormat)" }) -Join ',')
```

And expect the following to work around the issue in the initial question:

```
$Var = Invoke-Expression ((1..300 |% { "($_, 2)" }) -Join ',')
```

Comment: It works!  Nice find.  I tried many things myself but Invoke-Expression didn't even cross my mind  +100 to iRon

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer - just documenting some research to save others some time...

I can repro the issue here with the following code:

```
$xl = new-object -com excel.application;
$xl.Visible = $true;

$workbook  = $xl.Workbooks.Add();

$worksheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item(1);

$worksheet.Range("A1") = "aaa|111";
$worksheet.Range("A2") = "bbb|222";
$worksheet.Range("A3") = "ccc|333";
$worksheet.Range("A4") = "ddd|444";
$worksheet.Range("A5") = "eee|555";
$worksheet.Range("A6") = "fff|666";
```

which builds a new spreadsheet like this:

[image]

If you then run the following it will parse the contents of column A and put the results into columns B and C:

```
$range  = $worksheet.Range("A:A");
$target = $worksheet.Range("B1");

# XlColumnDataType enumeration
# see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcolumndatatype
$xlTextFormat = 2;

# XlTextParsingType enumeration
# see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xltextparsingtype
$xlDelimited = 1;

# XlTextQualifier enumeration
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xltextqualifier
$xlTextQualifierNone = -4142;

$var = (1,$xlTextFormat),(2,$xlTextFormat),(3,$xlTextFormat),(4,$xlTextFormat),(5,$xlTextFormat),(6,$xlTextFormat);

# parse the values in A1:A6 and puts the values in a 2-dimensional array starting at B1
# see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns
$result = $range.TextToColumns(
    $target,              # Destination
    $xlDelimited,         # DataType
    $xlTextQualifierNone, # TextQualifier
    $false,               # ConsecutiveDelimiter
    $false,               # Tab
    $false,               # Semicolon
    $false,               # Comma
    $false,               # Space
    $true,                # Other
    "|",                  # OtherChar
    $var                  # FieldInfo
);
```

which then looks like this:

[image]

However, if you change the declaration for `$var` to

```
$var = 1..6 | % { ,@($_, $xlTextFormat) };
```

you get the following error:

```
OperationStopped: The remote procedure call failed. (0x800706BE)
```

and the Excel instance terminates.

So there's *something* different about these two declarations:

```
$var = (1,$xlTextFormat),(2,$xlTextFormat),(3,$xlTextFormat),(4,$xlTextFormat),(5,$xlTextFormat),(6,$xlTextFormat);

$var = 1..6 | % { ,@($_, $xlTextFormat) };
```

but what that is eludes me :-S

Comment: do have any idea how to achieve this because, i m currently using this code 
`$var=(1,2),(2,2),.....(350,2)` I want to optimize the process that's y I raised the question.
I m ok with for-loop, for-each, or single line assignment anything......